# How to systematically build the access list for a transaction to make use of 'warm storage'?

Tags: gas, optimization

Say I have a transaction which will execute a function on a smart contract. This function will access storage, its own and that of other contracts, potentially multiple times. For example it may look up the ERC20 token balances for a set of addresses, etc.

By adding all accessed address - storage keys pairs to the access list of the tx before hand, I should be able to save on gas as 'warm storage' is cheaper to access.

How do I systematically build the access list for a tx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Geth (starting from version 1.10.2) includes a new `eth_createAccessList` RPC method that you can use to generate access lists. It is used like `eth_estimateGas`, but instead of a gas estimation, it returns something like this:

```
{
  "accessList": [
    {
      "address": "0xb0ee076d7779a6ce152283f009f4c32b5f88756c",
      "storageKeys": [
        "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "gasUsed": "0x8496"
}
```

Source: https://hackmd.io/@fvictorio/gas-costs-after-berlin#The-eth_createAccessList-RPC-method

Comment: How common is the usage of access list? The benefits seem very clear to me https://blog.infura.io/post/optimizing-ethereum-transactions-with-eth_createaccesslist, but i could not find many examples in practices

Comment: I know MEV bots use it, but in my experience only them, never a dapp.

Comment: Oh interesting. The authors of EIP-2930 argue that today Access lists are difficult to construct in real-time and hence there is only a 10% discount. But this might change in the future. Source: Security Considerations in https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2930?ref=infura.ghost.io

Answer (score 2):

## How to find storage slot

### 1. Using foundry

[Foundry's](https://getfoundry.sh/) forge & cast functions have a built-in way to get a layout of storage slots.

If working in a foundry project:

```
forge inspect <CONTRACT_NAME> storage
```

or, a deployed contract:

```
cast storage <ADDRESS> [SLOT]
```

### 2. Count yourself

You could also count the storage slots manually. You'd have to walk through the versions [storage slot layout](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.20/internals/layout_in_storage.html)

## More information

However... diving into this, I'm actually not sure how to make viewing storage more gas efficient in assembly/yul than just regular solidity.

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity 0.8.18;

contract GetWarmStorage {
    // 2,327 gas (gas to compare)
    uint256 public myNumberOne;

    uint256 private constant SLOT = 0;

    constructor() {
        myNumberOne = 123;
    }

    // 2,247 gas (-80 gas)
    function readStorageNormal() external view returns(uint256) {
        return myNumberOne;
    }

    // 2,332 gas (+5 gas)
    function readStorageAssembly() external view returns (uint256) {
        assembly {
            let result := sload(myNumberOne.slot)
            mstore(0, result)
            return(0, 0x20)
        }
    }

    // 2,291 gas (-36 gas)
    function readStorageAssemblyTwo() external view returns (uint256 result) {
        assembly {
            result := sload(myNumberOne.slot)
        }
    }

    // 2,310 gas (-17 gas)
    function readStorageAssemblyKnowingSlot() external view returns (uint256) {
        assembly {
            let result := sload(SLOT)
            mstore(0, result)
            return(0, 0x20)
        }
    }

    // 2,269 gas (-58 gas)
    function readStorageAssemblyKnowingSlotTwo() external view returns (uint256 result) {
        assembly {
            result := sload(SLOT)
        }
    }
}
```